# Trim the ' (apostrophe) character in an sql statement

Tags: sql, plsql, trim

I'm using the DBMS_SQL package that returns the value '12345' as a value for a column name.

How do you trim the apostrophes out from the value so that it could be converted into a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should trim the apostrophes:

```
substr(columnName, 2, length(columnName) - 2)
```

(As an aside, it's a pretty odd DB with a column name that's an integer, isn't it?)

Comment: Pretty odd design. Yes. Though it has its advantages.

Anyways, nicely done. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove leading and trailing apostrophes from a value:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(value,''''),'''')
```

or if you prefer:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(value,chr(39)),chr(39))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just use the "REPLACE" function to replace all single-quotes in the string with NULLs.

eg .
   with quotes :
   select 'Hello,''World''' from dual

quotes removed:
   select replace('Hello,''World''','''',NULL) from dual

But,  a columnname in Oracle cannot begin with a digit, so 12345 is invalid as a column-name anyway.